# dyld: Symbol not found: __TWPVs11AnyHashables20_AnyHashableProtocols

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode, alamofire

My app started crashing once I updated XCode to 8.3 with the below error:

```
  dyld: Symbol not found: __TWPVs11AnyHashables20_AnyHashableProtocols
  Referenced from: /Users/faidmit/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/C7E102B3-69B4-42EC-A699-0D2FDF768A86/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/341C0D73-B57B-4E30-A639-3A23B1D7CAA6/MVP-INT.app/Frameworks/Alamofire.framework/Alamofire
  Expected in: /Users/faidmit/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/C7E102B3-69B4-42EC-A699-0D2FDF768A86/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/341C0D73-B57B-4E30-A639-3A23B1D7CAA6/MVP-INT.app/Frameworks/libswiftCore.dylib
```

What have I tried:

- Cleaned and restarted.
- The framework is available in the Embedded
  Binaries part.
- I have changed the order to make sure that its the
  last one to be loaded (tried from the solution mentioning that
  CFNetwork should be after Foundation etc.)
- Made Alamofire optional.

Comment: I was able to resolve the errors by building the framework for the same Deployment Target as my project. Should I delete this question now or let it be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**For most of the people stuck with the same problem, the steps mentioned in the question itself might work (in the same order).** What I did was kind of a last ditch effort. Something that I wanted to try before I just rolled back the update. Steps below:

1. Check the `Deployment Target` for your project (for me, this was 8.1)
2. Download `Alamofire` from [GitHub](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire) and check the `Deployment Target` (8.0).
3. Change the Deployment Target for `Alamofire` to match the one for your project (8.1).
4. Compile and include the generate `.framework` in your project.

I agree that this is not a universal approach. It may be difficult especially if you are using pods. Since I am not, it worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

For me, deleting the app's derived data solved the problem. In Xcode 8.3, this can be done by going to XCode > Preferences > Locations. There you will find the path of the derived data with a right arrow next to it. Clicking on the arrow should launch Finder with the path to Derived Data. There you should look for any folder whose name begins with your app name and delete it

Comment: Somehow deleting the Derived Data did not work for me. Neither did deleting the entire xcode cache from Library. Glad that it worked for you though.